# Search a specific string inside each index in an array scope (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting to learn angularjs (I'm a beginner so please be kind).

I'm making a poll app and I'm using angular to do this

I have a array scope called `items` which consists all the items that will be added to the poll.

```
$scope.items = []
```

I'm making an error handling script which would inform the user if a specific poll item is already at the `items` array and I cannot do the `indexOf` method in the array directly to search if an item already exists since my code would be adding numbers into the array directly like `1. item1` , `2. item2` , `3. item3` so I want to search through all indexes in the items[] and do the `indexOf` method inside the index to see if an item already exists.

I have this code which supposedly return `true` if an item already exists inside the array and would return `false` otherwise:

```
    //number of items in the array
    var itemNum = $scope.items.length + 1;
    //the item which the user entered
    var toBeAdded = $scope.pollItem;

    //try to search the items[] array if an item already exists
    var findItem = function (){
        for (var i = 0; i < itemNum-1; i++) {
            if ($scope.items[i].indexOf(toBeAdded) >= 0) {
                return true
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    //add the item into the poll if findItem() function returns false
    if (!findItem) {
        $scope.items.push(itemNum.toString() + " " + toBeAdded);
        $scope.pollItem = "";
        focus('pollItem');
    }else{
        alert('item already exists')
    }
```

but instead it is always returning "true" (even if my items array is empty). I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Thank you for anyone that can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you define a function by `var findItem = function() {...}`, you have to invoke it by `findItem()`, else it won't be executed and since `findItem` isn't null, then `!findItem` will always be `false` because `findItem` is recognized as `variable` by javascript.

so change `if (!findItem)` to `if (!findItem())` will solve your problem.

refer the code snippet below.

```js
var items = [];
var toBeAdded = {
  test: 'test'
};
var findItem = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
    if (items[i].indexOf(toBeAdded) >= 0) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
}

if (!findItem()) {
  items.push(toBeAdded);
} else {
  alert('item already exists');
}
console.log(items);
```

Comment: I feel stupid for missing that out. By the way thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: yeah sure! Thanks again!